# Php create a file if not exists

Tags: php, file-handling

I try to create files and write the contents dynamically. Below is my code.

```
$sites = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/';
$newfile = $sites.$filnme_epub.".js";

if (file_exists($newfile)) {
    $fh = fopen($newfile, 'a');
    fwrite($fh, 'd');
} else {
    echo "sfaf";
    $fh = fopen($newfile, 'wb');
    fwrite($fh, 'd');
}

fclose($fh);
chmod($newfile, 0777);

// echo (is_writable($filnme_epub.".js")) ? 'writable' : 'not writable';
echo (is_readable($filnme_epub.".js")) ? 'readable' : 'not readable';
die;
```

However, it does not create the files.

Please share your answers and help. Thanks!

Comment: i just had quite the same issue, i figured i was trying to create a file with invalid name >.<, eg $fname = $Datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') like a stupid

Answer (score 34):

Try using:

```
$fh = fopen($newfile, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
```

for testing if you can create a file there or not.

If you can't create the file, that's probably because the directory is not writeable by the web server user (usually "www" or similar).

Do a `chmod 777 folder` to the folder you want to create the file and try again.

Does it work?

Comment: Read the answer again. I didn't say anything about root folder. Let's assume you have a username like "bob". The web server runs as a completely different user (let's say "www"). "www" can't write "bob"'s folders, unless: 1) "www" is added to "bob"'s group and the folder has 775 permissions at least. 2) You change the owner of the folder from "bob" to "www" (using `chown`). 3) The folder is writeable by any user (it has 777 permissions, you can change them using `chmod`).

Comment: Never ever just set your folder or file permissions to 777. See [this post](http://superuser.com/a/273533/157802) for more information.

Answer (score 27):

To be sure that a file exists before doing anything with it you can just **touch** it:

```php
if (!file_exists('somefile.txt')) {
    touch('somefile.txt');
}
```

This will just create an empty file having the current time as creation time. The advantage over fopen is that you don't have to close the file.

You can also set the creation time, if you want. The following code will create a file with a creation time of yesterday:

```php
if (!file_exists('somefile.txt')) {
    touch('somefile.txt', strtotime('-1 days'));
}
```

However: You should care about the fact that a file's modification time will be changed if you use touch for files which already exists.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The point for the `if`s is that you might not want to change the file's creation or modification time if it already exists.

Comment: If you write to that file you will change it anyway

Comment: If you use fopen() on a file that does not exist, it will create it, given that the file is opened for writing (w) or appending (a).

Answer (score 26):

Use the function **`is_file`** to check if the file exists or not.

If the file doesn't exist, this sample will create a new file and add some contents:

```
<?php

$file = 'test.txt';

if(!is_file($file)){
    $contents = 'This is a test!';           // Some simple example content.
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);     // Save our content to the file.
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this command using shell, try this:

```
shell_exec("touch filename.filetype");
```

If you want to put contents in this file using shell, try this (if you do this, you do not need to touch it before this):

```
shell_exec("echo filecontent > filename.filetype");
```