# Create randomly generated url for content

Tags: php, web, random, generator

I'm making a mini-paste-website for myself, kind of like pastebin but much simpler. I need it to generate a random url (something like mysite.com/paste/ab8536dc2e, mysite.com?id=b91527a2ac, etc. format doesn't really matter) with the paste in it. How would I generate a url like that and have it lead to a page with something I submitted in it? I'm using PHP, I'd prefer to keep it as simple and plain as possible and not use anyting like MySQL, jQuery etc. unless needed.

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Comment: I'm not encrypting anything. I'm literally just making pseudo-randomly-generated URLs for each 'paste'.

Comment: Sure, I had read "not use anything like MySQL" to mean "no persistent storage" to map your pseudorandom URLs to each paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To generate random path you could use PHP's built-in [uniqid() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)
2. You need to store the list of generated paths (links) somewhere. If you don't want MySQL – it could be SQLite, Memcached or even a plain-text file. But you have to keep them somewhere.
3. Depending on your chosen framework, you need to setup routing – check that the link exists (see 2) and then display the appropriate content. If you decided not to use any framework, you can simply work around $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] global variable.

Comment: Instead of `uniqid()` I'd recommend building a string out of `random_int()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the the following function :

```
function randomURL($URLlength = 8) {
    $charray = array_merge(range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    $max = count($charray) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $URLlength; $i++) {
        $randomChar = mt_rand(0, $max);
        $url .= $charray[$randomChar];
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Call randomURL() to access it.

(Disclaimer: This is not my code, I "borrowed" it for a similar problem.)

Check ( [Php create a file if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580017/php-create-a-file-if-not-exists) ) for using that string to create a file on your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this and use the variable however you wish.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $randomSite = "http://my.site/paste/" . hash('adler32', $i);
}
```

Where $i can be anything you want, such as the total number of paste. **The for loop is not needed**